# rawQuery: bind or column index out of range

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to get user by his name like that:

```
public Cursor GetUser(String username)
{
    return m_dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = \' ? \'", new String[] { username });
}
```

But then I got an exception "bind or column index out of range". What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to use a parameter, but such parameters never need to be quoted.
Your query actually searches for a user named "`?`" (with spaces).

Just use `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?"`.

Comment: So, in the query I need to write `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?"` Or `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? "`(with padding space)?

Comment: The whitespace around a symbol doesn't matter in SQLite, you can use `name=?`, `name   =   ?   `, or anything in between. It was the single-quotes that caused the problem `name = '?'` (error).